# What is the use case of using @Qualifier in @Bean definition?

Tags: spring

I know meaning of @Qualifier and @Bean annotations but what is the point of using it in a code like this? Is this for overriding "loadBalancedRestTemplate" bean or what?

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("loadBalancedRestTemplate")
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateCustomizer customizer) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
    customizer.customize(restTemplate);
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use:

```
@Bean(name="loadBalancedRestTemplate")
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateCustomizer customizer)...
```

Or the one you posted interchangeably.

By default when using `@Autowired` spring will find a bean of the matching type and inject that bean. The problem is that if you have more than one bean of the same type, it won't know which one to inject. That's where you specify the `@Qualifier` or the bean name in the configuration, as per your code. In the `@Autowired` target you will then specify the same `@Qualifier` to tell Spring which bean is to be used.

A common use-case for `RestTemplate` is the need to make calls on multiple rest endpoints that work differently for some reason. In such cases it's common for example to use the `setErrorHandler` or `setMessageConverters` methods with different arguments based on the endpoint you are trying to call or to use the `RestTemplateCustomizer` as in your code.

In your specific case the customisations applied to `loadBalancedRestTemplate` depend on the provided `RestTemplateCustomizer`. Depending on how that object is created, your specific code may or may not be modified to simply return a new instance of `RestTemplate`.

As it stands, assuming that everything has been done for a valid reason, I can only speculate that:

- different `@Service` classes will make use of different `RestTemplate` instances to call different services
- there is another `@Bean` in your codebase that defines `RestTemplateCustomizer`
- other `RestTemplate` instances won't be using that `RestTemplateCustomizer`, thus making them differently than the one in the code you provided

Comment: Thx for the answer. So I can simply change it to `@Bean(name="loadBalancedRestTemplate")
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateCustomizer customizer)` without any side effects. Am I right? Because using @Qualifier in bean definition seems uglier to me. Using just bean with name is more sexier IMHO.

Comment: Yes. Make sure you test it though. Also, assuming that you're doing this for work, if this change is outside the scope of your current task you may want to delay it. It may be sexier but it's such a tiny change that it's hardly worth it unless you can afford to strive for absolute perfection.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) simple and concise answer found in `Spring Docs` would answer your question best:

> @Primary is an effective way to use autowiring by type with several
>   instances when one primary candidate can be determined. When you need
>   more control over the selection process, you can use Spring’s
>   @Qualifier annotation. You can associate qualifier values with
>   specific arguments, narrowing the set of type matches so that a
>   specific bean is chosen for each argument.